# S3 event notification to SQS: the kms configuration was not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I am trying to create an event on an s3 bucket so that it would send a notification message to an SQS queue.  However, I am getting the following error when trying to save the event on s3 on the AWS console:

Unable to validate the following destination configurations. The KMS configuration was not found(arn:aws:sqs:xx-region-X:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:MySQS).  Does anybody have an idea why this error message comes through?

The queue's policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:xx-region-3: XXXXXXXXXXXXX: MySQS/SQSDefaultPolicy",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "my-ID",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam:: XXXXXXXXXXXXX:root",
            "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
          },
        "Action": "SQS:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:xx-region-X:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:MySQS",
        "Condition": {
          "ArnLike": {
            "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName”
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: How's your key policy?

Comment: thanks @FabioManzano, have no idea, will have to look....why?